# How to get PixelFormat of a WriteableBitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

`Bitmap` has a `PixelFormat` which says it is 8bit, 16bit,.. which is not supported in Windows Phone.

```
bitmap.PixelFormat;
```

I need to know that for a `WriteableBitmap`, But I hasn't that value.

How can I get/calculate `PixelFormat` of a `WriteableBitmap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pixel format of the WriteableBitmap is indicated on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels(v=vs.95).aspx

> The format used by the Silverlight WriteableBitmap is ARGB32 (premultiplied RGB).